# Detect orientation change while using Extjs (NON sencha touch) api

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know that there is a orientationChange listener available for the viewport for touch. However there is no orientationChange listener available in the regular ext js (non touch) version of viewport.

How can I detect a orientation change in this case...

thanks
nohsib

Comment: When your screen orientation changes, does it change the layout of your application / browser? If so, check if the viewport fires a resize event.

Comment: @ lwan : Thankyou...I was thinking of the same...Will try it...however is it totally fool proof...will any tablets/phones have same height and width...

Comment: I don't think so. It will be different for each device, however there should be a ratio between height and width. If your screen goes from portrait mode to landscape mode, it will almost be like switching height and width. (this is not exact, but you can estimate that what happened is an "orientation change")